# Отправка и обработка push-уведомлений в Android приложении

Tags: json, firebase, android-push-notification, messaging

Итак, есть следующая ситуация: я отправляю в android приложение push-уведомление следующим образом:

По ссылке для запроса
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Я формирую json самого уведомления:

```
{
    "data": {
        "title": "Новое сообщение",
        "content" : "Привет)"
    },
    "to": "/topics/all",
    "priority": "high"
}
```

(Всё это делаю в Postman)

Все девайсы автоматически включаются в топик:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");
```

Уведомление прекрасно уходит, приложение его принимает, но в логах пишет TITLE = NULL, BODY = NULL (что, очевидно, ибо у меня нет секции notification в json).

Проблема в том, что не вызывается функция onMessageReceived!

Как пишут в инете: отправляйте уведомление с секцией data в json вместо notification, что я и делаю, но НИЧЕГО не происходит. Но если отправить с секцией notification, то уведомление прекрасно отрисовывается (обходя, конечно же, функцию onMessageReceived)...

Вот onMessageRecieved:
(прописал в нём println чтобы видеть, что функция вызывается)

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        System.out.println("+---------------------------------------------+");
        System.out.println("|------------ MESSAGE RECIEEVED! -------------|");
        System.out.println("+---------------------------------------------+");
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String title = data.get("title");
        String message = data.get("message");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_profile)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_profile))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Фрагмент манифеста (все сервисы прописаны):

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foregroundd"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foregroundd"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Прошу помощи, а то я уже пол интернета перелопатил и результата 0.
Что делать, как быть?

Comment: А вы девайс на топик подписали? `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("/topics/all");`

Comment: Т.е. подписали, но не приходит? Или забыли, подписали и теперь приходит?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/ЮрийСПб, Нет. Ещё в самом начале подписал и приходит с NULL в title и body, пропуская onMessageRecieved

Comment: Возможно вы как-то не так отправляете. Покажите как в постмане запрос выглядит. Особенно интересует тело запроса.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/ЮрийСПб,

Вот тело:
{
"to": "/topics/all",
 "data":{
      "title" : "Mario",
      "message" : "great match!"
    }
}

Прилагается:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=<auth_key>

Я вас уверяю, запрос правильный, и всё отлично отправляется

Comment: Странно. У меня это всегда работает. Попробуйте приоритет задать так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083727/3212712

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/ЮрийСПб, нет, приоритет ничего не решил..

Comment: Последняя идея: добавить это в сервис обработки сообщений в манифесте: `android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/ЮрийСПб, не помогло..

Comment: Ну... Других идей нет. Разве что у вас какая то адская прошивка или вы прибиваете намертво приложение перед отправкой пуша.

Answer (score 1):

РЕШЕНО!

В onMessageReceived обязательно нужно сделать такую проверку:

```
if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
    drawPush();
}
```

И в в самом начале прописать

```
super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
```

Теперь работает как часы